# ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 1: given 118649

Tags: machine-learning

I have been trying to use McFadden's R-squared from scikit-learn, but I’m getting an error. Here is the code:

```
# Calculate McFadden's R-squared
log_likelihood_model = -np.sum(y * np.log(y_pred_prob) + (1 - y) * np.log(1 - y_pred_prob))
y_pred_null = np.mean(y)  # Predicting the mean of y as a null model
log_likelihood_null = -np.sum(y * np.log(y_pred_null) + (1 - y) * np.log(1 - y_pred_null))
mcfaddens_r2 = 1 - (log_likelihood_model / log_likelihood_null)

print("McFadden's R-squared:", mcfaddens_r2)
```

But the output says:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py in to_series(right)
    237         else:
    238             if len(left.columns) != len(right):
--> 239                 raise Value`your text`Error(
    240                     msg.format(req_len=len(left.columns), given_len=len(right))
    241                 )

ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 1: given 118649
```

How can I fix it?  118649 is the shape of training data set.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 1: given n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58826825/valueerror-unable-to-coerce-to-series-length-must-be-1-given-n)

Answer (score 0):

It seem to be the shape of your training dataset, which is causing the error.

I write an example for your reference.

```
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
import numpy as np

y = np.array([1,0,1,0,1,0,1])
y_pred_prob = np.array([0.9,0.1,0.8,0.1,0.7,0.2,0.9])

# Calculate log loss for the model
log_likelihood_model = log_loss(y, y_pred_prob)

# Calculate log loss for the null model (predicting the mean of y)
y_pred_null = np.full_like(y, np.mean(y))
log_likelihood_null = log_loss(y, y_pred_null)

# Calculate McFadden's R-squared
mcfaddens_r2 = 1 - (log_likelihood_model / log_likelihood_null )

print("McFadden's R-squared:", mcfaddens_r2)
```

The output is

```
McFadden's R-squared: 0.9911374675292574
```